# Does ISTIO support's Hooking?

Tags: hook, istio

Does ISTIO provides support on Hooking  [Methodology to augment a service request with additional information to let the load balancing and dynamic routing algorithms properly route it, WITHOUT needing to change the invocating or serving service itself.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve that effect, if I understand you correctly, by [Istio Route Rules](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.routing.v1alpha1.html). You can [match](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.routing.v1alpha1.html#MatchRequest) the rule [by a cookie or by a URL path](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.routing.v1alpha1.html#MatchCondition), and then influence [Load Balancing](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.routing.v1alpha1.html#LoadBalancing) or [Routing](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.routing.v1alpha1.html#RouteRule).